# zsh: how can I load the complist module - so I can get access to the menu-select widget?

Tags: zsh

According to the documentation in `man zshcompsys`, there is a widget `menu-select` that is defined in the `complist` module.

> If you  use  the
>          menu-select  widget,  which  is  part  of  the zsh/complist module, you
>          should make sure that that module is loaded before the call to compinit
>          so  that  that  widget  is  also re-defined.

`man zshmodules` also mentions:

> Note, however, that complist will not automatically  be loaded if it is not linked in:  on systems with dynamic loading, `zmodload zsh/complist' is required.

So I have added this in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
# .....(other stuff)
#
# load complist module to make "menu-select" widget available to zle
zmodload zsh/complist
autoload -Uz complist
complist
# Load zsh's completion system "compsys"
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# ....
```

however on zsh startup, I get this output

> .zshrc:44: complist: function definition file not found

What I'm actually trying to do is load the widget `menu-select`, if anyone can offer a solution that does that - whether it involves loading  `complist.so` or not that would be great

- my OS - **Ubuntu 16.04.1**
- my zsh - version **5.1.1**

For completeness, the reason I am trying to load menu-select is because I want to be able to bind it to a key combination and call it manually, I can use zstyle to get menu-select completion, (I believe when `menu-select` is invoked this way the completions system does everything needed to bootstrap `menu-select`) but the `zstyle` way I can't control/call the widget manually.

Comment: Where in the man pages tells you to autoload complist?

Comment: @llua good question.  I dont think the man page does say to  autoload complist. they only mention "you should make sure complist is loaded" I assumed - perhaps mistakenly? - that you autoloaded simply because thats how other features, e.g. compinit were loaded

Comment: You loaded complist with zmodload zsh/complist, nothing else is needed. you are free to bind the widget after that.

Comment: @llua I tried what you said and it worked! thanks for the help. I'm guessing the reason `complist` gets loaded with `zmodload` is because it is a module written in C. and `compinit` is written in `zsh` scripts placed somewhere in `fpath`? therefore for future usages, if the module is a `module.so` file in a directory like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh/5.1.1/zsh` then use `zmodload`, if the module is somewhere in `fpath` then it (probably) should be autoloaded.